# Is "anytimes" actually a word?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I talk to my coworkers on Skype and they always say "anytimes," "of course," or "no problem" when I thank them for helping me.

Today, I googled "anytimes" and Google suggested that it should be "anytime" without an s. So, I am curious if "anytimes" is the correct word to say in this context.

P.S. my coworkers are American.

Comment: If they're native speakers, no way are they saying "anytimes."

Comment: But even natives slack off in internet chat, ha.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that it's just slang. Thank you/thanks would have "thankies", among many others. Anytimes might be just like that.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not a word. I could not find it anywhere. COCA shows the result but it is **just one**.

However, I'm not sure whether native speakers utter 'anytimes' even in their most informal language. Let them comment.

What we use is 'anytime'. However, be cautious using ['anytime' and 'any time'](http://grammarist.com/spelling/anytime-any-time/).